# limit of integral

Tags: integration, limits, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I've been studying the topic of Lebesgue integral for the last few days. Whilst making some exercises on this topic I got stuck with a problem that goes as follows: Let for every $\varepsilon > 0$, the set D($\varepsilon$) be defined as
$$D(\varepsilon) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 0 < x^2 + y^2 < \varepsilon^2\}$$
I need now to deterimine the limit of the following integral
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{D(\varepsilon)}\frac{1 + \sin(x) + \sin(y)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} d(x,y)$$
The first thing I tried to do was to look at the absolute value of  the above equation. By doing this I could get an upper bound for the integrand given by
$$\frac{1+x+y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$
Changing variables to polar coordinates i could compute a upper bound for the limit i needed to calculate, which resulted in the following expression
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_{D(\varepsilon)}\frac{1 + \sin(x) + \sin(y)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} d(x,y) \leq 2\pi$$
With the same reasoning I also found a lower bound equal to $-2\pi$, but this is were I got stuck since I don't know how to go further in this problem. The result of the limit should be $2\pi$, however I can't conclude this solely based on the upper bound I found. I also don't see how to find another lower bound that would be equal to $2\pi$ so I might think that I'm approaching this problem with the wrong method. Does anyone have a tip like a different method or a tip involving the method that I'm using. Any help would be grealty appreciated :)).

Comment: Maybe the limit as x goes to 0 is a typo?

Comment: oh yes excuse me it should be epsilon going to zero

Comment: Try Taylor expanding $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(y)$ and exchange the integral and sum. Then switch to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrals $\int_{D(\epsilon)}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,d\lambda(x,y)$ and likewise with $\sin(y)$ are both $0$ due to symmetry (make the change of variables $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,y)$ or $(x,y)\mapsto (x,-y)$ respectively, and use the fact that $\sin$ is an odd function). Hence, the integral in question is
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{D(\epsilon)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,d\lambda(x,y)&=\frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{r}\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta=2\pi.
\end{align}
So, the integral is equal to $2\pi$ for all $\epsilon>0$, so the limit is also $2\pi$.

Comment: I get it now, thank you very much for your help :))